# How to change path of debugger?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-code, path

when i want to debug my code in c# I have a problem. I saw that it is most likely because I have a folder named "Michał" and not "Micha". anyone know where I can change the path to this debugger?

```
    PS C:\Code\cs>  & 'c:\Users\Micha\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.24.0\.debugger\vsdbg.exe' '--interpreter=vscode' '--connection=874a5847a90444aab691de8de0e08549' 
& : The term 'c:\Users\Micha\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.24.0\.debugger\vsdbg.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spell
ing of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:4
+  & 'c:\Users\Micha\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.24.0\.d ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (c:\Users\Micha\...ugger\vsdbg.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

content of launch.json file: (generated automaticly)

```
{

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "WARNING01": "*********************************************************************************",
            "WARNING02": "The C# extension was unable to automatically decode projects in the current",
            "WARNING03": "workspace to create a runnable launch.json file. A template launch.json file has",
            "WARNING04": "been created as a placeholder.",
            "WARNING05": "",
            "WARNING06": "If OmniSharp is currently unable to load your project, you can attempt to resolve",
            "WARNING07": "this by restoring any missing project dependencies (example: run 'dotnet restore')",
            "WARNING08": "and by fixing any reported errors from building the projects in your workspace.",
            "WARNING09": "If this allows OmniSharp to now load your project then --",
            "WARNING10": "  * Delete this file",
            "WARNING11": "  * Open the Visual Studio Code command palette (View->Command Palette)",
            "WARNING12": "  * run the command: '.NET: Generate Assets for Build and Debug'.",
            "WARNING13": "",
            "WARNING14": "If your project requires a more complex launch configuration, you may wish to delete",
            "WARNING15": "this configuration and pick a different template using the 'Add Configuration...'",
            "WARNING16": "button at the bottom of this file.",
            "WARNING17": "*********************************************************************************",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net6.0/cs.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "stopAtEntry": false
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please, update your question regarding Code of Conduct: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=DO%20NOT%20post%20images%20of%20code%2C%20data%2C%20error%20messages%2C%20etc.%20%2D%20copy%20or%20type%20the%20text%20into%20the%20question.

Comment: sorry for the mishap, I will fix it

Comment: It seems you just have a typo in how you call this script. There shouldn't be any problems using unicode characters in path names.

Comment: Do you know where to change it? I really don't know  @PMF

Comment: @Michał What do you do to get this error? There must be some script attached to your project (e.g a post-build script). This is not output from the compiler.

Comment: @PMF i just create console app by  write "dotnet new console" in terminal and instal c# extension. If i turn off c# extension I get another error instead: 'the configured "coreclr" debug mode is not supported' (in launch.json)

Comment: Can you add the contents of that launch.json to the question, please?

Comment: @PMF added. just in case the absolute program path is C:\Code\cs\bin\Debug\net6.0

Comment: I'm not a vscode expert, but here I can see nothing obvious. At least this isn't the script that fails, I think.

Comment: i remember that i had the same problem with python, but there was settings.json file and i could change path, but i dont see this in c# extension. is it possible to change the path to install new extensions in other place?